# Delphi Indy IdUdpClient read operation, No data returned

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, indy, udpclient, indy-9

I need to read the information that is sent by an electronic device (using UDP protocol). I am having problems using Indy components (version 9) in Delphi 7. Below you can see my code.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  buffer: Array of Byte;
  bytes_received: integer;
begin
  SetLength(buffer, 36);
  IdUDPClient1.Host:='192.168.1.1';
  IdUDPClient1.Port:=49152;
  IdUDPClient1.BufferSize:=36;

  IdUDPClient1.Active:=True;
  IdUDPClient1.ReceiveTimeout:=50;
  bytes_received:=IdUDPClient1.ReceiveBuffer(buffer,Sizeof(buffer));
  IdUDPClient1.Active:=False;
end
```

The output value of "bytes_received" is 0, and obviusly, "buffer" content is not what I expect... What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Imanol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `TIdUDPClient` the way you are, you are creating a static association between the remote `192.168.1.1:49152` pair and whatever random local IP/Port pair that `TIdUDPClient` binds to. Only packets sent from `192.168.1.1:49152` to that IP/Port can be received.  The device needs to know where to send its packets to, and you need to receive them on the IP/Port that they are sent to.  I don't recall offhand if `TIdUDPClient` has `BoundIP` and `BoundPort` properties in Indy 9, but it does in Indy 10.

`ReceiveTimeout` is expressed in milliseconds. Even if you have `TIdUDPClient` set up properly, 50ms is a very short amount of time to wait for data to arrive, so `ReceiveBuffer()` could simply be timing out. Try using a larger timeout value, at least a few seconds worth.

Alternatively, use `TIdUDPServer` instead. Set up its `Bindings` property with the local IP/Port pair(s) you want to receive data on, and then let its `OnUDPRead` event tell you whenever new data arrives from any remote IP/Port.

Comment: ... so I will have to use Indy 10 or use a UDP server